# Playing audio using pwm

Tags: pi-3, audio

I am a beginner and confused regarding playing sound over pwm on raspberry pi 3. I have added the following line in /boot/firmware/config.txt:
dtoverlay=audremap,pins_12_13

I have my speaker connected to a 2.5W classD amplifier from adafruit. Where the A+ pin is connected to gpio 12 on the pi and A- is connected to ground. I have tried to change the audio output settings when choosing device profiles by right clicking on the speaker. Even if i change it and turn of that the sound plays over HDMI it still plays over HDMI instead of the speakers.
I am playing the sound using the pygame library:

```
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(sound.mp3)
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(1)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

while pygame.mixer..music.get_busy()
     pygame.time.wait(100)
```

The OS used is:
Raspberry Pi OS 64bit

Can anyone please help me understand what is going wrong?

Comment: Are you using Pi OS Bookworm?

Comment: What software are you using to play a sound?

Comment: Right now I am using the pygame.mixer library to play the sound, but I am not sure if that is the library i should be using

Comment: And which OS? Update your question with this info.

Comment: Question is updated!